# Leer los datos de un archivo txt y guardar la informacion en un arrayList Java

Tags: java, array, archivo, arraylist

Tengo que hacer un programa que crea un archivo donde se almacenan los datos de una mascota (perro) y pueda acceder a lo guardado cuando vuelva a inicializar el programa.

Tengo el siguiente método de creación del archivo (me basé en un tutorial de un blog):

```
public static void crearMascotas() {
    FileWriter flwriter = null;
            
try {
        //crea el flujo para escribir en el archivo
        flwriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Testing\\Mascotas.txt");            

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (flwriter != null) {
            try {//cierra el flujo principal
                flwriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Este es mi metodo con el que añado las mascotas nuevas al archivo:

```
public static void agregarMascota(ArrayList lista) {
FileWriter flwriter = null;
            
try {//además de la ruta del archivo recibe un parámetro de tipo boolean, que le indican que se va añadir más registros 
            flwriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Testing\\Mascotas.txt", true);
            BufferedWriter bfwriter = new BufferedWriter(flwriter);
            for(Mascotas mascota:(ArrayList<Mascotas>) lista) {
                //escribe los datos en el archivo
                bfwriter.write(mascota.getId() + "," + mascota.getNombre() + "," + mascota.getSexo() + "," + mascota.getRaza()
            + "," + mascota.getColor() + "," + mascota.getSenia() + "," + mascota.getComportamiento() + 
                   "," + mascota.getTamanio() + "," + mascota.getEdad() + "," + mascota.getEstado() + "," + mascota.getDuenio() + "," + mascota.getHistorial() + "\n");
            }
        
            bfwriter.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
    if (flwriter != null) {
                try {
        flwriter.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }
    }
        }
}
```

Y este es mi metodo con el que intento leer los datos del archivo (en el tutorial lo ocupan igual pero al momento de correrlo en mi programa me marca errores que desconozco):

```
public static ArrayList leerMascotas() {
    // crea el flujo para leer desde el archivo
File file = new File("C:\\Testing\\Mascotas.txt");
ArrayList listaMascotas = new ArrayList<>();    
Scanner scanner;
    
try {
        //se pasa el flujo al objeto scanner
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            // el objeto scanner lee linea a linea desde el archivo
    String linea = scanner.nextLine();
    Scanner delimitar = new Scanner(linea);
    //se usa una expresión regular
    //que valida que antes o despues de una coma (,) exista cualquier cosa
    //parte la cadena recibida cada vez que encuentre una coma              
    delimitar.useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");
            
    Mascotas e = new Mascotas();
            
    e.setId(delimitar.next());
    e.setNombre(delimitar.next());
    e.setSexo(delimitar.next());
    e.setRaza(delimitar.next());
    e.setColor(delimitar.next());
    e.setSenia(delimitar.next());               
    e.setComportamiento(delimitar.next());
    e.setTamanio(delimitar.next());
    e.setEdad(delimitar.next());
    e.setEstado(delimitar.next());
    e.setDuenio(delimitar.next()); //Aqui dice que hay error cuando se corre
    e.setHistorial(delimitar.next());
    listaMascotas.add(e);
        }
        
//se cierra el ojeto scanner
scanner.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
        return listaMascotas;
}
```

Los errores son los siguientes:
[image: Errores que me salen]

El otro error es en la linea siguiente en el metodo main:

```
ArrayList <Mascotas> listaMascotas = new ArrayList <Mascotas> ();
    listaMascotas = ArchivosMetodos.leerMascotas(); //Aqui marca el otro error
```

En si solo quiero extraer los datos para ocuparlos de nuevo en el programa por medio de un arrayList.
Agradecería mucho la ayuda o correcciones que me puedan brindar.

Comment: La cosa tiene pinta sencilla... usas `next()` y te dice literalmente *No hay más elementos*. Estás seguro de que la línea que estás leyendo tiene todo lo que necesitas?? Que tu regex está cogiendo las cosas bien separadas por coma??

Comment: te sugiero agregar un ejemplo de la entrada queprovees

Comment: Te voy a ser honesto, apenas estoy empezando con la programación así que me perdí con tu comentario. En el archivo todo está separado con comas y en el tutorial que me guíe si funciona de la misma forma en que lo tengo. No veo algo por el cual tenga que fallar en esas líneas y agradecería la ayuda para darme cuenta de que es lo que estoy pasando por alto y aprender

Comment: `crearMascotas` está cerrando el archivo siempre que terminas de ejecutar el método, porque siempre pasas por el finally de ese try-catch. Está bien liberar los recursos, pero hay que saber bien cuándo y acá el FileWriter está cerrado al final del método, .

Comment: **ArchivosMetodo** es una clase o una instancia de esa clase? o en que clase tienes tu metodo main??